# react-navigation@^4 createAppContainer crash with 'Cannot read property getStateForAction of undefined'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I tried to run react-navigation v4 on my project however it keeps crashing on launch

I reset cash a hundred times, check every versions are consistent with each others, and follow step-by-step the HelloWorld of react-navigation doc, nothing works even on a simplistic example :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('some-app-name', () => App);

export default createAppContainer(() => <Text>LOL</Text>);
```

Relevant package.json part :

```
{
....
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-navigation": "^4", // resolving to react-navigation@4.0.10
....
}
```

The error is coming from Component.router which is null in the createAppContainer HOC constructor, specifically:

Error message is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStateForAction' of undefined

(from @react-navigation/src/native/src/createAppContainer.js line:131)
https://github.com/react-navigation/native/blob/master/src/createAppContainer.js

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it, the composed Component inside createAppContainer MUST be a navigator, or the Component.router (check the source code) property will not be here.